# SAS macro: How to sort a sequence of "," separated numbers using SAS macro without using any proc steps?

Tags: sas

Here are comma-separated values as follows:

```
15,30,16,8,86,98,6
```

The question is using SAS macro language to sort these numbers by ascending order and descending order and **output them into SAS log**.
I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
%macro sorts (values=);
%let val = %sysfunc(countw(&values.,','));
%do i=1 %to &val.;
    %let str1= %scan(&values.,&i.,',');
        %do j=&i.+1 %to &val.;
             %let seq = %bquote( );
             
            %let str2= %scan(&values.,&j.,',');
            %if &str1. < &str2. %then %do;
                %let tmp = &str1.;
                %let str1 = &str2.;
                %let str2 = &tmp.;
                %let seq = &str1.;
         %end;
         %put &str1.;
  %end;
%end;

%mend sorts;

%sorts(values=%str(15,30,16,8,86,98,6));
```

I realized that because I never changed the value of **str2** in the created array **&values.** so that I can't get the final sorted results. I know, maybe this is not the only reason.
Could anyone be so kind as to help me improve this code above or if there is a better way to accomplish this task?
The question is **using SAS macro, no proc steps.**

Comment: Why the limitations of no data step and must be macro? Limiting yourself like that is inefficient. You haven't accounted for ties though, that's an issue for starters.

Comment: Post the logic that you think you're using to sort here or your comments about what you think the code is doing here. I'm having hard time following your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your logic.

1. Determine the number of items in your list first, and assign that to a macro variable
2. Use the SMALLEST() function to get the nth smallest value iteratively. Use a %DO loop to iterate.

This handles ties correctly as well.

```
    options mprint symbolgen;
    %let str = 15, 30, 16, 8, 86, 98, 6, 6, 100, -9;
    %let new_list = ;
    
    %macro sort(list=);
        %let nWords = %sysfunc(countw(&list.));
        %global new_list;
        %let new_list = %sysfunc(smallest(1, %unquote(&list)));
            
        %do i=2 %to &nwords;
            %let element = %sysfunc(smallest(&i, %unquote(&list)));
            %let new_list = &new_list, &element;
        %end;
        
    %mend;
    
    %sort(list=%quote(&str));
    
    %put &new_list;
```

Just a suggestion, when dealing with code like this, first generate the pseudo code or your logic and then create the code. The logic used here is similar to what you'd learn in a first year programming course of how sorts work and should really NEVER be used in actual code. This is solely useful as a programming exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap DATA step function string literal function arguments in `%str()` instead of in `''`

```
%let val = %sysfunc(countw(&values.,','));
```

Should be

```
%let val = %sysfunc(countw(&values.,%str(,)));
```

Personally, if it were an assignment, I would give the prof a little poke in the eyes and use `SORTN` call routine.

Example:

```
%macro sortn (values=);
  %local nvalues i args comma;
  %let nvalues = %sysfunc(countw(&values.,%str(,)));
  %do i=1 %to &nvalues;
    %local x&i;
    %let x&i = %scan(&values.,&i.,%str(,));
    %let args = &args &comma x&i;
    %Let comma = ,;
  %end;
  %let comma =;

  %syscall sortn(&args);

  %do i = 1 %to &nvalues;%superq(comma)%superq(x&i) 
    %let comma=,;
  %end;
%mend sortn;

%put %sortn(values=%str(15,30,16,8,86,98,6,1));
```

LOG

```
575  %put %sortn(values=%str(15,30,16,8,86,98,6,1));
1,6,8,15,16,30,86,98
```

Q2: Does this show a deeper understanding of macro than intended?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy enough to do in a data step.  Works best if you know the number of items in the list.  Example:

```
data _null_;
  array x [10] _temporary_ (&str);
  call sortn(of x[*]);
  call symputx('list',catx(',',of x[*]));
run;
```

So to convert this to macro just take advantage of the SYSPARM option and the DOSUBL() function.

```
%macro sort() / parmbuff ;
%local n rc list ;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&syspbuff,( , )));
%if &n %then %do;
  %let rc=%sysfunc(dosubl(%qsysfunc(dequote("
data _null_;
  array x [&n] _temporary_ &syspbuff;
  call sortn(of x[*]);
  call symputx('list',catx(',',of x[*]));
run;
"))));
  %*;&list
%end;
%mend sort;
```

Example usage:

```
174   %put %sort(15, 30, 16, 8, 86, 98, 6, 6, 100, -9);
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


-9,6,6,8,15,16,30,86,98,100
175   %put %sort(5 6 3 10);
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


3,5,6,10
```